# .NET: NET 2.0 SP1 versus NET 2.0 SP2?

Tags: .net

I am using VS2005 which seems to be shipped with .NET 2.0 SP2.  If I distribute my app with .NET 2.0 SP1, will there be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will most be no problem unless there is a specific bug in SP1, but not in SP2 that your application triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are some "things" (classes) added in SP1 that weren't present in "SP0". ( http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CatchingRedBitsDifferencesInNET20AndNET20SP1.aspx )